# Cut a Substring of a String which was read by serial in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I tried to find an answer but I couldn't solve my problem.
I read a signal with my raspberry via the serial command. This works perfect. I receive a String of a special length. The code is shown below:

```
import serial
import time
import re

ser = serial.Serial(
port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
baudrate =19200,
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS)

ser.open()
ser.write('send' + '\r\n')
time.sleep(1)           # gives the device time to answer 
out = ser.read(48)      # size=48 equals one line output
```

One example of the output looks like this:

```
aw=   1.100 T=  94.2 'C  H20=   530 ppm
```

Because there are 3 values in one line I tried to separate the 3 values from the String to get 3 Substrings with only the values. 
First I did this to separate only the value of aw:

```
aw = re.search('aw=(.+?)T', out).group(1)
```

Then I receive a Substring like this: ___1.100

But then I still have the spaces left in the String. I tried to cut the spaces with aw.strip() but it doesn't work. The problem the amount of spaces varies from the value and if I get higher temperatures I get less spaces so I can't just cut of 3 spaces.
Is there anything special with spaces read with serial or is there anything I forgot to cut off the spaces? I tried it with a normal String it works, but with the String I have read with the serial command it doesn't.
Thanks for the help!
Max

Comment: why dont you use `split` instead??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> out="aw=   1.100 T=  94.2 'C  H20=   530 ppm"
>>> [float(v) for v in out.split() if not v.strip('0123456789.')]
[1.1, 94.2, 530.0]
```

If you want to assign the values to variables:

```
>>> aw, T, h2o = [float(v) for v in out.split() if not v.strip('0123456789.')]
>>> print aw, T, h2o
1.1 94.2 530.0
```

#### How it works

`split` will separate out the strings:

```
>>> out.split()
['aw=', '1.100', 'T=', '94.2', "'C", 'H20=', '530', 'ppm']
```

The next issue is that we want to remove the annotations and just keep the numbers.  The strings that are numbers consist of nothing but `0123456789.`.  So, if a string contains any other character, we want to skip over it. To do this, we remove all non-number characters by `v.strip('0123456789.')` and if any characters remain, we skip the string.

So, `v.strip('0123456789.')` is non-empty (True) if there are one or more non-number characters in the string.  Thus, `not v.strip('0123456789.')` is True only if all the characters belong in a number.

As examples, here we use this test to show that `1.2` is a valid number but `H2O` is not:

```
>>> not 'H2O'.strip('0123456789.')
False
>>> not '1.2'.strip('0123456789.')
True
```

Thus, the list comprehension converts the valid numbers to floats and ignores the other strings.

Comment: thanks a lot it works well, but I do not understand the if not part of the command

Answer (score 0):

```
aw=\s*(\S+)\s*T
```

You can change your regex to this.Your code will works fine without giving any spaces.

```
aw = re.search('aw=\s*(\S+)\s*T', out).group(1)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/27